# Is there an ABAP Workbench in SAP Business One 2007?

Tags: abap, sapb1

Here comes a simple question but hard to find its answer.

Is there an ABAP Workbench (also known by the transaction code SE80 in SAP R/3) in SAP Business One 2007?

The workbench should be open and not just for SAP use. I would like to know if it's possible to create custom ABAP programs in this SAP solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to find the answer at all if you bother searching. There is no ABAP Workbench in B1 because B1 is not built on top of the NetWeaver/ABAP stack.

Answer (score 1):

SAP Business One is not built on NetWeaver platform, so there will be no way you can have an ABAP application server. Also, for your information, SBO is not a R/3 Structure .About the technical part in SBO, it has a SQL database and you can only write SQL queries to retrieve data and generate reports. There is a query generator to help you write queries. To conclude, data processing in SBO is very limited comparing to ABAP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either .NET/Java for customising or developing screens in SAP Business One.

It doesn't have any relation with ABAP and there are no transaction codes in SAP Business One.

Answer (score 0):

> About the technical part in SBO, it has a SQL database and you can only write SQL queries to retrieve data and generate reports. There is a query generator to help you write queries. To conclude, data processing in SBO is very limited comparing to ABAP.

But once you have the data you can do whatever you want with it, for e.g the now native Crystal Report rutime in SBO...Also it has a a pretty rich and mature COM-based SDK for putting data in as well, the DI API (as well as the DI Server which is XML-based). I create solutions for SBO with these all the time in my job...